# Django SECRET_KEY unique for same project on each workstation?

Tags: django

Quick Django question. I know these are unique for every project and shouldn't be shared as it is part of the hashing algorithm, I think.

However, if you are working on the same project on multiple workstation, the `SECRET_KEY` would be the same on all of them since it is the same project? Or unique to each workstation?

If it is part of the hashing algorithm, I would think it would be by project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret key of a Django project is unique to that project. It is created when you start the Django project. So if you are sharing a common code base and just working on different workstations, then yes it would be the same secret key. If each workstation is hosting a different Django code base then you could use different secret keys.

Comment: can you provide any references from which you are getting this information?